# Laravel pagination removes duplicate keys when preserving pagination query

Tags: php, laravel

When using `$posts->appends(request()->query())->links()` Laravel will remove duplicate query params keys. For example:

`?business_model=physical&business_model=www`

become this:

`?business_model=www&page=2`

How to avoid this?

Comment: PHP doesn't handle multiple query params of the same name anyway (it will ignore all but one), unless you use array style: `?business_model[]=www&business_model[]=www`. Can you use that style?

Comment: Not really, guess I will need refactor JS part and build query string like so: business_model=www,physical

Comment: I don't think your style of query string is considered valid anyway. It is possible to work around it manually, but I have never seen anyone using that style.

Comment: URLSearchParams.append() led me to this. Tried use URL() and URLSearchParams().

Comment: Consider using `set()` instead of `append()`.

Comment: Bu then I will not be able to set multiple options for same keys, as `set` will override old value.

Comment: Yes, because like I said, multiple values of the same name are considered wrong anyway. In your case, to make these params work with PHP you need `name[]` convention anyway.

Comment: I did some research and some people claim that PHP's way of parsing query string is weird. But if you want to have it work smooth with Laravel, you need to change your convention. If you want to stick to your current query string style, you'd need to do some manual query string parsing, which is possible by reading `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and transforming it to convenient array or object.